# Can't select a single vertex in Blender 2.9

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to learn so I started a basic first model, a shield.

I am at a point where I want to UV map the model smoothly with no stretching. But I have a problem, I need to make a seam at a point where I have no vertices. I could make a new vertex, but to do that, I need to select a vertex to make a new vertex. But, when I try select one, I get multiple vertices selected as well. I tried deselecting the ones I didnt need, but when I did, I just deselected the whole thing again. [image]

[image]

I selected the red point, When I did, all the vertices within the blue circle also got selected.

I have no clue why this happens and hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: We're really going to have to see your blend file to work out exactly what's going on [uploading details here](https://blend-exchange.com/help), but you could try turning off proportional editing by clicking the blue and white dot in the middle of the header bar to see if that makes any difference first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the solidify modifier. The two vertices are 'connected' to the original vertex.
If you apply the modifier you'll be able to select the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it's not selecting the vertices on the left and right, only the ones in the centre. It's selecting both the top and bottom vertices (in the centre) because there is a solidify modifier which is adding thickness to the model procedurally. If you want to change the single vertex on the top, you would need to apply the solidify modifier.